# Change SMTP server for SBS 2011 Self Monitoring Reports

Tags: windows, windows-sbs-2011, ssrs, smtp

SBS 2011 sends daily/weekly/instant reports from the account SBSMonAcct@. It uses localhost as the SMTP transport as being SBS Exchange is usually installed.

I want to use an external SMTP server. Where can I change these settings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can.  I think it's hard-coded.

I have SBS08, not SBS2011, but apparently [they both use the `Windows SBS Fax Sharepoint Receive Connector`](http://www.nogeekleftbehind.com/2011/12/09/show-exchange-message-size-limits-in-sbs-20082011/) for the SBS console mail.  This is set to allow all connections from 127.0.0.1 anonymously.

Your best bet would probably be to set up some kind of SMTP server with similar properties, [perhaps the one that came with IIS7](https://serverfault.com/questions/455724/what-replaces-iis-smtp-server-in-windows-server-2012)?

(I can't test this because I have 2008 *and* Exchange, but it might be worth a shot.)

Comment: Yeah I already have an SMTP server set up on the server. I was hoping to remove it from service. Not to worry, looks like no-one knowns.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're running an unsupported configuration, and I think they just didn't include a way to do what you're trying to do.  Sorry.  :(