# SMTP Relay suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, smtp, microsoft-office-365

Our SMTP relay has been stopped, we are using office 365 email account for this purpose. I have searched a lot on the net but unable to find the solution.

Our environment is based on below Server (all are **Windows 2012 R2**)

- 1 Axapta 2012 R3 Server
- 1 SQL Server
- 1 - Entperise Portal Server - **SMTP relay is configured here**
- 1 - Domain controller

We are using this relay to send email alerts to our staff generated by Ax.
I tried these few things,

- Verified the office 365 account and it is working fine.
- Tried to manually create an email and pasted it into the **Pickup** folder and instantly it got picked from there and moved to **Queue** folder, but from **Queue** folder it is not going out and all the emails are held there.
- Verified from Axapta client and generated an email from Ax client, it is getting generated and arriving in the **Queue** folder, but same as above

I also uninstalled SMTP as a feature from the Server and re-installed it but again **no LUCK !!!**

-- Update log

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-03-22 07:50:21
#Fields: time c-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status 
07:50:21 172.16.11.16 QUIT - 240
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-03-22 07:50:46
#Fields: time c-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status 
07:50:46 172.16.11.16 cls - 500
07:50:58 172.16.11.16 QUIT - 240
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-03-22 07:53:21
#Fields: time c-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status 
07:53:21 172.16.11.16 QUIT - 240
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-03-22 07:54:06
#Fields: time c-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status 
07:54:06 172.16.11.16 QUIT - 240
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-03-22 07:55:17
#Fields: time c-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status 
07:55:17 172.16.11.16 QUIT - 240
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-03-22 07:58:15
#Fields: time c-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status 
07:58:15 172.16.11.16 QUIT - 240
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-03-22 08:00:34
#Fields: time c-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status 
08:00:34 172.16.11.16 QUIT - 240
```

Please advice, tried so many things.

Comment: This sounds like an IIS SMTP Server, correct? [Enable logging](http://itswapshop.com/tutorial/how-enable-logging-iis-smtp-server-windows-server) first as it should show you the problem. Also notice, that SMTP in IIS is [deprecated](https://serverfault.com/questions/455724/what-replaces-iis-smtp-server-in-windows-server-2012) so it's probably a better idea to use a separate SMTP server.

Comment: @Esajokinen, yes you are right it is IIS SMTP Server. I have enabled logging. Also can you suggest any names regarding SMTP server as a replacement of IIS SMTP server?

Comment: If you have enabled logging, why won't you share the information? We can't guess what could be wrong without the actual information. And no, we do not give product recommendations here.